# Google Sheets IMPORTXML Text Field from Website

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to dynamically pull in car values for cars matching specific criteria on Kelley Blue Book.  I have this `IMPORTXML` query that has a link to the specific page that shows the trade-in value of the car.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.kbb.com/Api/3.9.462.0/71553/vehicle/upa/PriceAdvisor/meter.svg?action=Get&intent=trade-in-sell&pricetype=FPP&zipcode=12345&vehicleid=411852&selectedoptions=6762567|true|6762674|false|6762900|false|6762905|false|6762909|false|6762913|false|6762915|true|6762926|false|6762928|false&hideMonthlyPayment=False&condition=verygood&mileage=40000", "//text[@y='-8']")
```

In this URL, there is a text field that has the y coordinate as -8.  I was hoping that it would be sufficient to identify the data I want to pull in (The trade-in value).  I get the standard Can't fetch URL error and can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is not within your XPath `"//text[@y='-8']"` but with the website itself.

basically you have two options to test if the website can be scraped:

```
=IMPORTXML("URL", "//*")
```

where XPath `//*` means "everything that's possible to scrape"

and direct source code scrape method:

```
=IMPORTDATA("URL")
```

sometimes is source code just huge and Google Sheets can't handle it so this needs to be restricted a bit like:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("URL"), 10000, 10)
```

anyway, non of these can scrape anything from your URL

Comment: Interesting.  Thank you for the clarification and the syntax to check "scrapability"